# Issue with updating mysql database content by using a html form

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-update, crud

I have a page that I am making a very simple CMS for, the page displays 3 products, it grabs the Title, The Description, The Price, Product Includes, and Product Not Includes from the database. That works, what does not work is a form I created to easily change the content in my database. Right now, when I fill out the form, instead of adding all the data from the form to the database, all the data in the form except for the last input field will get added. If I only try to update a single item in my database by using a single field, then only that item gets update but all other items get deleted.

Here is my code.

```
 <h2>Deal 1</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="#">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Title: </label><br><input type="text" name="title1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1title); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Description: </label><br><textarea style="height: 200px;" name="desc1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1desc); ?>"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Price: </label><br><input type="text" name="price1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1price); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Include: </label><br><input type="text" name="include1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1inc); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Not Include: </label><br><input type="text" name="notinc1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1noinc); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

And here is the Connection

```
<?php

    $connect =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'specials' );

//Error Check//

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect)){
            echo "failed to connect";}


    $fetcher = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM specials WHERE id=1");

    $fetcher2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM specials WHERE id=2");

    $fetcher3 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM specials WHERE id=3");

    $deal1 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetcher);
    $deal2 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetcher2);
    $deal3 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetcher3);


    //Insert Data
    //mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO deal_1 (title) VALUES ('Galapagos')");
    //Deal 1
    $deal1title=$deal1["title"];
    $deal1desc=$deal1["description"];
    $deal1price=$deal1["price"];
    $deal1inc=$deal1["include"];
    $deal1noinc=$deal1["notinclude"];
```

Here is my db update form

```
        <h2>Deal 1</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="#">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Title: </label><br><input type="text" name="title1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1title); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Description: </label><br><textarea style="height: 200px;" name="desc1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1desc); ?>"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Price: </label><br><input type="text" name="price1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1price); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Include: </label><br><input type="text" name="include1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1inc); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Not Include: </label><br><input type="text" name="notinc1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1noinc); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

And here is my db update php code

```
 <?php

    //Get Data Deal 1

    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

    $getTitle1=$_POST["title1"];
    $getDesc1=$_POST["desc1"];
    $getPrice1=$_POST["price1"];
    $getInc1=$_POST["include1"];
    $getNoInc=$_POST["noinc1"];
        //Set Title
        if(!empty($getTitle1)){
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title='$getTitle1' WHERE id='1'");
        }
        //Set Description
        if(!empty($getDesc1)){
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET description='$getDesc1' WHERE id='1'");    
        }
        //Set Price
        if(!empty($getPrice1)){
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET price='$getPrice1' WHERE id='1'");
        }
        //Set Include
        if(!empty($getInc1)){
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET include='$getInc1' WHERE id='1'");
        }
        //Set noinclude
        if(!empty($getNoInc)){
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials set notinclude='$getNoInc' WHERE id='1'");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Your code has quite some flaws which could result in unexpected behaviour. Also, this is a lot of text for a propably minor problem. Could you try to isolate the problem? Your SQL seems syntactically corrent, although you should have a look into `prepared statements`. Also, id is a number, therefore `WHERE id = 1` is ok

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Thank you, I added error reporting and right away it flagged out an issue. Looks like I had notinc1 on my form, but had noinc1 on my php code, I also removed the single quotes around my id number and now it looks like all works fine. Thank you all